# TextBox Cursor is NOT blinking

Tags: wpf, focus, caret

I have a WPF datagrid (4.0) with a custom column (derived from DataGridTextColumn).

In GenerateEditingElement I create a custom textbox control (with an additional button) and like to set the cursor into it so that the user can directly start editing.

The closest I get is that the caret is shown but is not blinking and I need an additional click to start editing.

All other stuff (binding, ...) is working nicely

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Since the caret is shown, but not blinking, then I am guessing your control has Logical Focus,  but not Keyboard Focus.

How are you setting the control as Focused?

`myControl.Focus();` will give the control logical focus, but it won't respond to keyboard events because it doesn't have Keyboard focus. To give an element KeyboardFocus, use

```
Keyboard.Focus(myControl);
```

This is because WPF allows you to define multiple Focus Scopes, and each scope can have it's own focused element, however only one control in the entire application can have Keyboard Focus

Comment: I moved tx.Focus() to the Loaded-Event of my custom control (which in fact is only a user-control ;-) and that worked as a workaround

Comment: If it's not having the keyboard focus, then how come the caret is showing up?

Comment: @AbdulSaleem a TextBox with logical focus, but not keyboard focus, will show a solid non-blinking caret. This is an uncommon scenario but one you can easily engineer. See e.g. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38507/Using-the-WPF-FocusScope for a screenshot.