# WPF TextBox focus "sticking" after disabling and enabling

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, focus

I have a TextBox in a Grid that has InputBindings such that when I hit return, a search is performed in a background thread.

The `IsEnabled` property of the TextBox is bound to a `bool` property in my ViewModel called IsSearching, which is true while the background thread is running (I use a converter to negate the value).

I type in TextBox and hit enter, starting the search and disabling the TextBox. When the background thread completes, the TextBox is enabled, however the focus is messed up:

The caret is still inside the TextBox however it does not blink, and I am unable to type. I believe the TextBox has focus, but not "`KeyboardFocus`".

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Look at that answer:

[TextBox Cursor is NOT blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010272/textbox-cursor-is-not-blinking)

Like you said maybe you must set the focus to the keyboard