# WPF: Restore keyboard focus after re-enabling container

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, focus

I have a Window with a Grid with two TextBoxes in it. One of them has keyboard focus. If I disable the Grid and then re-enable it some time later, the keyboard focus is not restored to the TextBox that previously held it.

What actually happens is that the cursor is shown but not blinking...

I've tried setting the focus on the TextBox in Grid's IsEnabledChanged event, but none of the approaches I've tried work (Keyboard.SetFocus, txtBox.Focus, FocusManager methods...)

**NOTE:** I disable and enable the Grid in Dispatcher thread, so it's not a threading issue. Also, Keyboard.FocusRestoreMode is set to Auto.

Has anybody faced this problem? Is there a way around this? What I've managed to deduce is that when Grid's IsEnabledChanged fires, the TextBox is still disabled. But I could't find an event that would fire when Grid's content is enabled also.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8010272/1997232). Try to set focus via dispatcher`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => textBox.Focus());`.  The problem here is what `IsEnabledChanged` is occurs before layouting, so setting focus directly doesn't work, but it should via dispatcher (as it will occurs some times later).

Comment: @Sinatr: Yeah, that seems to do the trick! Thanks a million. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: This solution is still helpful 4+ years later. My symptoms were even stranger: I had a *blinking* cursor in the textbox, but no keyboard response. WPF should obviously never allow such a state, but there it was. Thanks @Sinatr.